# How I can know the dns server configured in my Wi-Fi router?

Tags: android, dns, dhcp

I am trying a long time discover the dns I am using when I am connected in a DHCP wireless network.

I tried to use `DhcpInfo dhcp = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo(); dhcp.dns1` but returned my router IP (192.168.0.1).

I want to know the dns configured in the wireless router, the true DNS, like 8.8.8.8. It's possible know this from my app?

Thanks in advance,
Matias Schimuneck

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you will be able to tell as your router is being a DNS forwarder and therefore will always mask the outside DNS server.